# What is the difference between the Adi Sankar's concept of Ishvara and Krishnaprem's concept of Ishvara?

Tags: adi-shankaracharya, krishna-prem

Krishnaprem (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krishna_Prem) was a great devotee and Philosopher who wrote essays on the Gita and the Kathopanishad. He was a Gaudiya Vaishnava but respected all views.

What is the difference between His concept of Ishvara and Adi Sankar's concept of Ishvara, as revealed from the writings of the two?

Kindly cite proper references.Thanks.

Comment: If he is gaudiya vaishnava, then it will be same as jiva goswami's view, is it not?

Comment: He was also a realised soul, and He had His original views I think, as seemed to me by going thru His Gita.